# How to customized properties folder in wicket

Tags: localization, wicket

in my application I have about about 20 pages, Each page have about 4 properties file for each language. Now all properties have to be in same directory as is *. java file. Is there option to change in ? I want to create new directory properties and here add all properties file. Or is there option to add all localized message in one file ? Problem is that in page a.hmtl properties "name" has value "a" and in another page b.html has the same key another value: "name" value "b"

I try to add

```
        this.getResourceSettings().addResourceFolder("/properties");
```

but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt find easier solution. I write my own class where I changing path to my properties:

```
package org.toursys.web.finder;

import org.apache.wicket.util.resource.IResourceStream;
import org.apache.wicket.util.resource.locator.ResourceStreamLocator;

public class CustomResourceStreamLocator extends ResourceStreamLocator {

    @Override
    protected IResourceStream locateByClassLoader(Class<?> clazz, final String path) {
        String newPath = path;
        if (newPath.endsWith(".properties")) {
            newPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/properties" + path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));
        }
        IResourceStream stream = super.locateByClassLoader(clazz, newPath);
        if (stream == null) {
            stream = super.locateByClassLoader(clazz, path);
        }
        return stream;
    }

}
```

and then I add this stream locator to my app

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the example on the [wicket-library](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/customresourceloading/). There are several different ways to archieve this. I'm sure you'll find one that suits your needs.

Short version: For maximum control you'll have to write your own [IResourceStreamLocator](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/util/resource/locator/ResourceStreamLocator.html) along with your own [IResourceStream](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/util/resource/IResourceStream.html) and set wicket to use them in Application.init().

Answer (score 2):

> Now all properties have to be in same directory as is *. java file

Not at all, the properties file does not need to be next to the java file necessarily. The property files are scanned following the default lookup algorithm, as described in the [Wicket Free Guide](https://code.google.com/p/wicket-guide/):

> 1. ComponentStringResourceLoader: implements most of the default algorithm. It searches for
>      a given resource across bundles from the container hierarchy, from class hierarchy and from the
>      given component.
> 2. PackageStringResourceLoader: searches into package bundles.
> 3. ClassStringResourceLoader: searches into bundles of a given class. By default the target
>      class is the application class.
> 4. ValidatorStringResourceLoader: searches for resources into validator's bundles. A list of
>      validators is provided by the form component that failed validation.
> 5. InitializerStringResourceLoader: this resource allows internationalization to interact with the
>      initialization mechanism of the framework that will be illustrated in paragraph 15.4.

Read more in chapter 12.4.

If you want to keep it simple I would recommend you to have just one property file for each language. These property files could be located next to your application class e.g.

```
WicketApplication.properties.xml
WicketApplication_en.properties.xml
WicketApplication_zh.properties.xml
WicketApplication_de.properties.xml
```

This method saves you from looking through several localization files and avoids bugs originating from complex message overriding rules.

Comment: you mean without .xml right ? But translation should depend on page. In page a.html key with name "login" should be translate different as in page b.html. Is there option to implement this ?

Comment: Xml-property files are recommended if you need characters outside ISO-8859-1. See https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/everything-about-wicket-internationalization.html

Comment: You can perfectly well manage with single translation file per language if you separate the message keys into namespaces.