# Conflicting warnings about location of wicket.properties in Wicket 7

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-7

I have a dashboard library that we use at our company. It has an Initializer. The wicket.properties file is stored in the same package as the rest of the code, not in a META-INF folder. After upgrading to Wicket 7 I started noticing the following warning:

/wicket.properties location is deprecated. Please move the file to /META-INF/wicket/ folder and give it a name that matches your packages' name, e.g. com.example.myapp.properties

So I thought, no problem, I'll just follow the instructions in the well written message and move the properties file and rename it. I renamed the file to com.redi.wicket.dashboard.properties and moved it to META-INF/wicket folder. Now I get the following warning:

/META-INF/wicket/*.properties doesn't work in OSGi and single-jar environments and is not supported anymore! Please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5997 for more details and report an issue for the library that still uses it.

I looked at WICKET-5997, WICKET-6030 AND WICKET-5713 and tried to piece together what I was supposed to do.

I've noticed in the Application class there are deprecated methods regarding this and one, collectWicketProperties, that will be removed in 7.3.0. So I'd like to get this fixed while it is fresh on my mind and not have it bite me down the road when I upgrade.

So where do I put my initializer properties file and what do I name it?

Thanks

Comment: A link with some helpful information; may be not similar question though;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961935/how-to-customized-properties-folder-in-wicket

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out by looking at the code for org.apache.wicket.Application. Here the developers mention that you should use the ServiceLoader class for Initializers. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5997. I noticed the Application.initInitializers method and saw the ServiceLoader class they were talking about.

So I read up on the java.util.ServiceLoader class and it states the following:

*A service provider is identified by placing a provider-configuration file in the resource directory META-INF/services. The file's name is the fully-qualified binary name of the service's type. The file contains a list of fully-qualified binary names of concrete provider classes, one per line.*

So I created a META-INF/services folder and put a text file named org.apache.wicket.IInitializer and inside the file I put the fully qualified class name of my IInitializer implementation.

The warning went away and my Initializer was called on application startup which is exactly what I wanted.

**NOTE:** If you are migrating from using wicket.properties make sure to take out the "initializer=" part of the file. The new way is not a properties file so it doesn't have key value pairs. It only has fully qualified class names separated by new lines. See the java.util.ServiceLocator documentation if you need more details.

Also if you are using maven, the META-INF/services folder will go in src/main/resources.